# Make an overlay widget in flutter to slide in and out from top of the screen

Tags: flutter, animation, overlay, flutter-animation

I created an overlay widget which can be displayed and removed after 3 seconds at the click of a button.

This is my view

```
  OverlayState? overlayState;
  OverlayEntry? entry;

  bool _isVisible = false;
  bool btnClicked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Overlay Example',
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 12),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isVisible = true;
                  });
                  displayOverlay(_isVisible);
                  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isVisible = false;
                      displayOverlay(_isVisible);
                    });
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Press Me'))
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```

These are the functions that are used to control the overlay widget

```
 void displayOverlay(bool isClicked) {
    if (isClicked == true) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showOverlay());
    } else {
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => hideOverlay());
    }
  }



  void hideOverlay() {
    entry?.remove();
    entry = null;
  }
```

This is the widget that is Overlayed on the screen

```
  void showOverlay() {
    entry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => AnimatedPositioned(
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        top: _isVisible ? 0 : -MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        child: Container(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
          child: Material(
            color: const Color(0xff2D2B36).withOpacity(0.6),
            shape: ShapeBorder.lerp(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
              0.5, // Interpolation value between 0.0 and 1.0
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final overlay = Overlay.of(context)!;
    overlay?.insert(entry!);
  }
```

I would like to know how I can make the overlay widget slide in from top of the screen then slide out after 3 seconds without using any flutter package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle showing and hiding animation of the banner inside its widget. Can use `AnimationController` to control showing/hiding the banner and animate it.
`FractionalTranslation` can be used to specify the vertical position from top to bottom based on the height of the banner itself (its values can range from -1 to 1) and Franctionally translates based on widget's size itself.

The idea is that we add the `OverlayBanner` widget to the overlay and itself will show with animation and hide.

To remove the overlay entry when the animation is done can call a callback `onBannerDismissed` which is passed from the parent and the parent widget that added the entry can remove it.

```
class OverlayWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverlayWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OverlayWidget> createState() => _OverlayWidgetState();
}

class _OverlayWidgetState extends State<OverlayWidget> {
  OverlayEntry? entry;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(''),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Overlay Example',
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 12),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                displayOverlay();
              },
              child: const Text('Press Me'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void displayOverlay() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showOverlay());
  }

  void hideOverlay() {
    entry?.remove();
    entry = null;
  }

  void showOverlay() {
    entry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => OverlayBanner(
        onBannerDismissed: () {
          hideOverlay();
        },
      ),
    );

    final overlay = Overlay.of(context)!;
    overlay.insert(entry!);
  }
}

class OverlayBanner extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverlayBanner({Key? key, this.onBannerDismissed}) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback? onBannerDismissed;

  @override
  State<OverlayBanner> createState() => _OverlayBannerState();
}

class _OverlayBannerState extends State<OverlayBanner>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  static const Curve curve = Curves.easeOut;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    );

    _playAnimation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      builder: (context, child) {
        final double animationValue = curve.transform(_controller.value);
        return FractionalTranslation(
          translation: Offset(0, -(1 - animationValue)),
          child: child,
        );
      },
      animation: _controller,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.purple,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _playAnimation() async {
    // fist will show banner with forward.
    await _controller.forward();
    // wait for 3 second and then play reverse animation to hide the banner
    // Duration can be passed as parameter, banner will wait this much and then will dismiss
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    await _controller.reverse(from: 1);
    // call onDismissedCallback so OverlayWidget can remove and clear the OverlayEntry.
    widget.onBannerDismissed?.call();
  }
}
```

PS: No need to `setState` as well, can use `AnimatedBuilder` and pass a child to it which is the banner content, this is a more optimal way because the banner content (purple container) won't rebuild by every animation tick.

[image]